# NVD3 multi bar chart with json?

Tags: json, nvd3.js

I'm trying to load json into NVD3's multi bar chart, but can't get it to render the values that I'm including. I'm not sure what "stream_layers" is doing, either.

It is similar to this (http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBar.html), but should render a series of "mini" graphs next to each other, rather than one large graph of all the combined values. NVD3 calls this multiBarChart.html in their example files. I can get a blank graph to show up, but I can't get it to pull the values.

```
var test_data = [{
    "key" : "MT_ATTEMPTED",
    //"bar": true,
    "values" : [4505891, 20130620, 6636631]
}, {
    "key" : "MT_SUCCESS",
    "values" : [4505891, 20130620, 6636631]
}, {
    "key" : "MO_ATTEMPTED",
    "values" : [4505891, 20130620, 6636631]
}].map(function(series) {
    series.values = series.values.map(function(d) {
        return {
            x : stream_layers(3, 3, .1),
            y : d[1]
        }
    });
    return series;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to have key/value pairs within a top level key.

Also:

```
.map(function(series) {
 series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d.label, y: d.value } });
 return series;
```